# Helpers.js in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I exported functions that I will reuse on the helpers.js file but when I'm importing it. my useStates is not defined anymore.

ProductPage who uses the helpers.js
this is my useState that is being undefined when I imported all those functions

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

import { Link } from "gatsby"

import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite"
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles"

import { addFavorite, removeFavorite, isProductInFavorites, getAllFavoriteProducts } from "../../helpers"

const ProductList = ({ products }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const [favorites, setFavorites] = useState(getAllFavoriteProducts())

  return (
    <>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        {products?.map((product) => {
          return (
            <div className="ProductCard" key={product._id}>
              <div>
                <Link to="/shop" state={{ shop: product.shop }}>
                  <img
                    className="ProductImage"
                    src={product.imagePrimary}
                    alt={product.name}
                  />
                </Link>
                <div className="FavButton">
                  {isProductInFavorites(product) ? (
                    <FavoriteIcon
                      fontSize="small"
                      style={{ fill: "red" }}
                      onClick={() => removeFavorite(product)}
                    />
                  ) : (
                    <FavoriteIcon
                      fontSize="small"
                      style={{ fill: "gray" }}
                      onClick={() => addFavorite(product)}
                    />
                  )}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="ProductCardDetails">
                <div className="NameAndPrice">
                  <div className="ProductName">{product.name}</div>
                  <div className="ProductPrice">P{product.price}</div>
                </div>
                <div className="Description"> by {product.shop.name}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductList
```

helpers.js

here on my functions I used the favorites to pass the data but it's undefined when I'm on the ProductPage.

```
function getFromLocalStorage(key) {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key))
  }
  
  function setToLocalStorage(key, data) {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(data))
  }
  
  export const favoriteProductsStorageKey = "favorites_products"
  
  export function addFavorite(product) {
    const isProductAlreadyFavorite = isProductInFavorites(product)

    if (isProductAlreadyFavorite) return

    const newFavoriteProducts = [...favorites, product]

    setFavorites(newFavoriteProducts)
    setToLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey, newFavoriteProducts)
  }

  export function removeFavorite(product) {
    const newFavoriteProducts = favorites.filter(
      (iteratedProduct) => iteratedProduct._id !== product._id
    )

    setFavorites(newFavoriteProducts)
    setToLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey, newFavoriteProducts)
  }

  export function isProductInFavorites(product) {
    return favorites.some(
      (iteratedProduct) => iteratedProduct._id === product._id
    )
  }

  export function getAllFavoriteProducts() {
    return getFromLocalStorage(favoriteProductsStorageKey) || []
  }
```

question is how can I use my functions again? I can't seem to figure it out.
I'm getting an error
[image]

Comment: what is the detailed error message you get?

Comment: https://imgur.com/NcD1e0C here are the errors. @Yalamber

Comment: Can you share the code of the component where you have declared the state variable?

Comment: hello edited my question @Shuvo

Comment: so you are trying to save your component state in to localstorage?

Comment: Yes, what I'm doing is I'm saving the favorite product to my localSTorage. then I exported each function because I have another component that will use that function. @Yalamber]

Comment: it seems like you are calling setFavorites inside helper functions where it is undefined as you won't be able to use those functions used to set component local state outside in helpers functions it is out of scope in that helper functions

Comment: what should be my approach?

Comment: Is it due to mis-matched eslint configs?

Answer (score 0):

Your `setFavourite` and `favourite` variables used in local state component are out of scope in your helpers file, you won't be able to call those functions from outside your component scope. You will either need to use some kind of state management library like redux for this.
Also need to mention this, It seems like you are trying to save your component state in to localStorage,
There are hooks available that you can use for this. You can look in to source code for this hook
https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/